How to handle long datatype between 64-bit Unix and Windows Applications?
I'm working on a C++ Client Server Application where client is on Windows and Server is on AIX. Both the existing applications are on 32-bit and we are planning to move them to 64 bit.
As per the investigation I could see that 64 bit machine long datatype is taking 8 bytes of memory on AIX and it remains 4 bytes on windows. There should be lot of calls between Server and client to exchange the data through these long datatypes
One thing I'm sure is that , we are not crossing the range (2147483647) of these long variables at both server and client any more.
Question : Will there be any issue if I migrate my applications to 64 bit ? If yes how can I handle this scenario?
I haven't tried anything yet.....

C++ data types don’t really matter, the only thing that matters is the definition and implementation of the data exchange. If it’s done correctly there will be no issues whatsoever. If not, it can break in many ways.

It's best not to use long in portable code, use int32_t or int64_t instead

Simple answer don't do it yourself, use an RPC libarary like protobuf/gRPC. There are many more pitfalls than the 64 bit issue when transporting data between two different architectures (assuming you also have structs etc). This explains a bit of the problems profobuf, and this gives you an introduction to gRPC

You should never use types like int, long if you have strict requirements about their size, because it is implementation defined. Use fixed size types instead (int64_t, uint64_t, int32_t etc.).

Agree with the recommendations in the comment. Move to an existing RPC library before porting to 64 bits, not at the same time, else debugging is a lot harder.

Don't change the communication protocol, then you can migrate the two components separately. (A note: the server-side could should be tested on Linux/amd64 as well, for two reasons: 1. the endianness problems will come out (Aix: big endian, Linux/amd64: little endian) 2. you can use valgrind to find memory leaks and some other bugs.

Will there be any issue if I migrate my applications to 64 bit?

Yes. Since underlying hardware is being updated, the application code possibly behave in uncertain ways.

If yes how can I handle this scenario?

Try wrapping up your application layer into a docker container and deploy your docker container.
Docker deployment stays agnostic to underlying hardware (unix or windows), resulting in expected behaviour of programs.
While running docker, you will be required to specify the platform, https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/


"Put an MFC application in a Docker container" is not exactly the sort of advice that helps anyone.

What version of Docker would you use on AIX OS?
